# How to execute a .run file using Mac Terminal?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, command

Once I navigate to a certain directory that has a .run file in it, how do I execute that file using mac Terminal?

I have change the chmod 777 for fileName.run file and run it

```
$ chmod 777 file-name.run
$ ./file-name.run
```

but it does not work for me. any idea ?
it give me the following error.

```
$ ./ppasmeta-9.4.1.3-linux-x64.run: cannot execute binary file
```

Its postgres plus advanced server for linux I want to install on mac os-x .

Comment: I have change the chmod 777 for .run file.

Comment: ./run-file, did you try ? and instead of commenting question related information, put it in question itself

Comment: Whatever you are trying to achieve, granting everyone write access to a file you plan to execute is a **serious security problem** -- you should revert to sane permissions (maybe `chmod 755`) immediately.

Comment: Two questions... 1) What's in the file? 2) Please run `ls -l file*` and click `edit` under your question and paste the result in.

Comment: 3) What do you mean by *"it does not work"*? What happens exactly?

Comment: It give me "cannot execute binary file" error

Comment: I think there is compatibility issue, I cannot run(execute) linux specific file on mac os-x.

Comment: It doesn't look like Postgres Advanced Server is available for OSX http://www.enterprisedb.com/ppas-platform-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Muhammad Iqbal, you won't be able to run a Linux-specific binary/executable on Mac OS X without some modifications. It's like attempting to run an .exe on Linux - without wine. While Linux and OS X are similar, they are not that compatible. If you can get your desired program in the form of a .deb, that may work. If not, I would suggest either dual-booting your Mac with a small Linux distro (ie. DSL) or picking up a virtual machine. I've dual-booted before - it's a decent option for this situation if you have enough hard drive space. If another solution shows up, I'll be sure to let you know through this channel.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure what you are asking here but try this

```
./run
```

Answer (score -2):

As I said in the comments, I don't think that Postgres Advanced Server is available for OSX. If Postgres 9.5.3 is suitable for your purposes, you could install `homebrew` and use it to install Postgres 9.5.3 with:

```
brew install postgresql
```

You can download the one-liner to install `homebrew` from [here](http://brew.sh).